# mysqli_fetch_assoc inquiry

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem, and I can't really figure out what to do after reading documentation. Right now i'm making a quizz app for fun. Heres my PHP
code. The error lies in $question. Which I want to be an associative array of the actual query itself. I'm wondering how I can achieve what I want, because I feel like i've done something similar in the past but I just can't remember how

```
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>'
<?php

    // Set question number
    $number = (int) $_GET['n'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'questions'";
    $query.= "WHERE question_number = $number";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    $question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


?>
```

Comment: hint: `'questions'`

Comment: whats wrong with that?

Comment: I have that in my database

Comment: Backticks are for columns/tables. Quotes are for strings. You also are better off using parameterized queries. If another developer comes along and changes your assignment you'll be open to injections.

Comment: @cresjoy change `'questions'` to ``questions`` and you need a space between that and `WHERE`

Comment: ah... I'm always totally oblivious to these spaces and quotes. Apologies I am a beginner

Comment: There also is error reporting which would come in handy, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quotes for table names in MySQL. Use nothing or backtricks:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions";
// or
$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions`";
```